# Batch Renaming - Android Bootanimation - rename files with different steps between them from 1 to 100

Tags: android, batch-file, file-io, batch-rename, boot-animation

I have 100 consecutive PNG files, used in one boot animation. But with different steps between them

> **Example:** 1, 4, 5, 10, 14, 15, 16, 19...

Using [Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer) is enough, and it's a good application for this, but i love to do it with the old black screen with a batch file.

Can anyone give me an idea, how to rename them from 1 to 100 preserving the order of sequences?

Comment: Please, post the _original names_ of the PNG files (3 or 4 are enough) and the _new names_ you want...

Comment: from 1,4,5,10,14,15,16,19,20,21,22,25,26,27,30,32,33 to 001,002,..,100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be saved as batch file and called with the folder path as argument. By default, the current folder is processed

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem - Set folder to be processed
    set "folder=%~1"
    if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    rem - Prepare work environment
    pushd "%folder%" & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem - Load file list into array with number padding
    for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "*.png"^|findstr /i /r /x /c:"[0-9]*\.png"') do (
        set /a "n=100000000+%%~na"
        set "n[!n!]=%%a"
    )

    rem - Retrieve the list from memory and, for each element in the
    rem   array, rename the file to the correct name
    set "n=1"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set n[') do (
        set "name=000!n!"
        echo ren "%%a" "!name:~-3!.png"
        set /a "n+=1"
    )

    rem - Cleanup
    endlocal & popd 
    endlocal
```